# White Spaces using hidden for text field

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have a form with many Label and text Field, I want to show some Text Field only when a Picker View was selected, so I use `hidden = true` to hide my items, but there's a gap between two text fields because the middle the text field is hidden. How do I do it so I don't have a blank space ?

Screen:

### [image: picture 1]

[image: picture 2]

Comment: which versions of iOS are you supporting ?

Comment: @Wain The latest version I'm just coding on xCode and use the simulator I don't test on a device, I have the last xCode

Comment: When you are hiding the textfield and label. you have to change the frame of the label and textfield next to the hidden one

Comment: So you can use a stack view

Comment: @BalajiKondalrayal The height? what is the attribute to use it ?

Comment: @Wain for the all form ?

Comment: @Ben Could not get you? can u be clear

Comment: Yes, you could use (nested) stack views for the whole form. That's what they're designed for.

Comment: @Wain So stack view gonna compress the items ?

Comment: Yes, any items that are hidden means that part of the stack view (and any associated spacing) are removed / collapsed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want by using Auto Layout constraints with differing priorities.

1. Add a vertical constraint from the top of label 3 to the bottom of field 2 and give that a constant of `8` and a priority of `998`.
2. Add a vertical constraint from the top of label 3 to the bottom of field 1 and give that a constant of `8` and a priority of `997`.
3. Add an `@IBOutlet` to the constraint in step 2 to your code.  You can do this by finding the constraint in the *Document Outline* and <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging to your code.  Call it something like `field3Top`.
4. When it is time to hide field 2, set the `hidden` property for your text field 2 and label 2 to `true` and change the priority of `fieldTop.priority` to `999`.  This will cause this constraint to have priority over the other one and the gap will be closed.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var field3Top: NSLayoutConstraint!
   @IBOutlet weak var field2Label: UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var field2TextField: UITextField!

   field3Top.priority = 999
   field2Label.hidden = true
   field2TextField.hidden = true

   // for fun, you can animate the change with this code
   UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0) {
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   }
   ```
5. When it is time to show field 2 again, set `field3Top.priority = 997` and set the `hidden` properties back to `false`.

---

Here's a demo of the hiding in action:

[image: demo of hiding a field]

Comment: I don't know if I did a mistake, I put it in viewDidLoad, it doesn't work, I'm gonna see this, this week end

Comment: Make sure the constraint from label 3 to the bottom of text field 1 has a small constant.

Comment: Make sure your `@IBOutlet` is connected to the right constraint.

Comment: Thanks ! But if I want to hide many items, It would be hard to memorise the constraints, someone told me that it could be easely with stack view, it could compress the items is it true ?

Comment: I haven't worked with them yet.  They're for iOS 9 and above.

Comment: i can confirm that using a `StackView` will close the gap automatically on iOS 10.2